# How can I connect embedded Python to the console's I/O in a Windows GUI app?

Tags: python, c++, visual-studio-2010, python-2.7

I am making a Windows GUI app in C++ in Microsoft Visual Studio 2010. I want to include a Python debug console that can be opened up through the app. I have followed [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10215565/810671) to connect the C++ standard I/O to the console, but when I then embed Python, Python does not seem to be able to access the console through its standard I/O:

```
create_console(); // essentially the function in the answer I linked to above
Py_Initialize(); // initialize Python
printf("hello, world\n"); // works
PyRun_SimpleString("print \"hello, world\""); // does not work
```

I tried patching this up with the following:

```
PyObject *py_stdin = PyFile_FromFile(stdin, "<stdin>", "r", NULL);
PySys_SetObject("stdin", py_stdin);
Py_DECREF(py_stdin); py_stdin = NULL;

PyObject *py_stdout = PyFile_FromFile(stdout, "<stdout>", "w", NULL); // *
PySys_SetObject("stdout", py_stdout);
Py_DECREF(py_stdout); py_stdout = NULL;

PyObject *py_stderr = PyFile_FromFile(stderr, "<stderr>", "w", NULL); // *
PySys_SetObject("stderr", py_stderr);
Py_DECREF(py_stderr); py_stderr = NULL;
```

But not only do the lines marked with an asterisk (*) above cause a runtime error (the error message is nothing more than "Microsoft Visual Studio C Runtime Library has detected a fatal error in [APP_NAME].exe."), but Python's standard input still does not work, even though the input block above runs without errors.

Comment: What version of Python are trying to embed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your program needs to use the same Microsoft C runtime DLL as was used for the version of Python you're trying to embed. Python 2.7 is compiled with Visual Studio 2008 and uses `MSVCRT90.DLL` while you're using Visual Studio 2010 and `MSVCRT100.DLL`. Each DLL has it's own `stdin`, `stdout` and `stderr`, that's why your `create_console` function has no effect. The two DLLs also have different `FILE *` stream internal layouts, that's why it crashes when you pass a `FILE *` stream created using `MSVCRT100.DLL` to Python. It ends up trying to use it with `MSVCRT90.DLL`.

Basically to solve this problem you need to compile your application with Visual Studio 2008.

Comment: Is there any other workaround? Or is it possible to get a build of Python 2.7 that uses `MSVCR100.DLL` (or even to compile one myself)?

Comment: Rather, would this solve my problem: http://p-nand-q.com/python/building-python-27-with-vs2010.html ?

Comment: Yes, you can build your own version of Python 2.7 using Visual Studio 2010. Other possible workarounds are given here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24714436/3826372 The first workaround given there won't work in your case.

Comment: I should also add that this applies to any third party Python extension modules you might using. You'll need to recompile those with VS 2010 if you recompile Python.

Comment: Luckily I don't need any extensions (other than my own of course). Anyway, the build I linked to includes a lot of third-party extensions.